# Expect script accepting negative numbers but not positive numbers

Tags: expect

I have an expect script that is working if I pass it in a negative number.  However, it will now not accept positive numbers.  The values I am trying to pass are **-12345** and **12345**.  Here is my script:

```
spawn -noecho $servicecode --enable
expect "Do you want to continue*" { send "y\n" }
expect "password:" { send "${password}\n" }
expect "passcode:" { send -- "${passcode}\n" }
expect "*Service has been successfully enabled*"
expect eof
EOF
```

Now, if I remove the "--" from the expect statement, it now accepts positive integers but will no longer accept negative integers.  If I put back the "--", it accepts negative numbers but now not positive numbers.

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to send both positive and negative integers?

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp ...` and see what's happening.

Comment: What exactly happens with positive integers when you use `--`?

Comment: Tcl sees `send "-9\r"` as an option, not a value. Same thing happens in the shell, it's very difficult to get `echo` to print the string "-n". Just make it a habit to always use `send -- ...`, but especially when you're dealing with user input (like passwords)

Comment: @glennjackman, it's Expect's `send` who sees `-9\r` as an option, not Tcl.